# "Always-indent" style for visual studio express

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tabs, indentation, auto-indent

Is there a way to have Visual Studio (2012 Express) auto-indent like it is possible in **XCode** or **Emacs**? Saying auto-indent I mean that the IDE indents to the correct level when pressing `TAB` no matter what position in the line the cursor is in.

I know I can press `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+F` or `Ctrl+K,D` to indent a document or selection, but this is kind of cumbersome. Writing code and just pressing `TAB` to auto-indent the current line is just much faster. Is there a way to do this in VS?

Answer (score 0):

Go to
    `Tools -> Options`
choose then
    `Text Editor -> All Languages -> Tabs`
There you can specifiy:

- Tab size
- Indent size
- Insert spaces (instead of a tab)

Comment: This is not what my question was about. I already successfully set options to insert 3 spaces instead of tabs, this does however not solve the problem that e.g. VS will insert 3 spaces at the end of a line rather then auto-indent the current line when the cursor is at the end of the line and you press `TAB`.

Comment: @user826955 I see. You might have a look at [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) then, but I'm not sure if it works with VS 2012 already.